# How to define a ns uri modeltype for an own RDF Schema metamodel in qvto?

Tags: uri, rdfs, metamodel, cim, qvt

I've built an RDF schema Metamodel and want to define a modeltype for my RDF Schema.
I've these files : a metamodel uml (KB3Import.uml) and an other one in rdf schema (MyFirstProfile_CIMSdF_v6.rdf)

So I'd to do something like this on qvto :

```
modeltype KB3Import uses KB3Import('...');

modeltype MyFirstProfile_CIMSdF_v6 uses MyFirstProfile_CIMSdF_v6("...");

//transformation RDFS_2_UML(in RDFS : MyFirstProfile_CIMSdF_v6, out UML : KB3Import);

main() {
    
}
```

Does someone know how do with a local file for the ns uri (on the second line)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, Eclipse QVTo followed the OMG principle that the OCL / QVT is ignorant of the locations of the models; a magic proprietary catalog is needed in the IDE, or a URI mapping standalone. .settings/org.eclipse.m2m.qvt.oml.mmodel.urimap provides the catalog entries.

We finally got fed up with this unfriendly pain. The latest (3.10.6) release of Eclipse QVTo allows you to specify the physical location of your models directly as part of the modeltype.